# Is there a way to create a "global" hook that will fire regardless of the model requested

Tags: loopbackjs

I want to be able to add a row count to every model I have. I know how to add it using a remote or operational hook, but as far as I can tell you have to add that code to each model that you want to use it on. Instead, I just want write one hook that will trigger regardless of what model is requested.

Comment: All models are based on the PersisdedModel.  Perhaps if you hook into PersistedModel.prototype.[before|after]Remote()?

Comment: You could also create a [mixin](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-mixins.html) with your hook and then add it into your models.

Comment: In the details I mentioned that is what I want to avoid.  By the way I have been to Bruge and Antwerp, neat place.  My friend has family in Brudge.

Comment: Spelling Bruges

Comment: You mentioned that you dont want to add the hook implementation into each model. Adding a mixin is just one line in each model definition file. Anyway if that is too much, you could go with @YeeHaw1234 suggestion and if you don't want to touch a built-in model, you can extend the `PersistedModel` add your hook and then base all your models on this extended `PersistedModel`. Happy to see you enjoyed Antwerp/Bruges. Make sure to check Gent too if you have a chance.

Comment: My mistake I did not read your answer correctly, yes a mixin should work fine. Thank you both.  Go ahead and put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage a [mixin](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-mixins.html) functionality.

In `model-confg.js` specify a location of your mixins:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Create a mixin in your designated mixins folder (e.g. `server/mixins/<mixin-Name>.js`) :

```
module.exports = function(Model, options) {
  Model.observe('before save', function event(ctx, next) {
    // Your row count logic
    next();
  });
};
```

Add a mixin into your model:

```
{
  "name": "MyModel",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    ...
  },
  ...
  "mixins": {
     "MixinName": true
   },
  ...
}
```

Another option would be an extension of a built-in `PersistedModel`. You could add your hook to it and then base your models on this extended `PersistedModel`.